# How to get the state of checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, infragistics

I want to know the state of my chekcboxes when I check or uncheck them.

I'm creating checkboxes columns according to my DB (one column for one line in my table). I'm using Infragistics 2015.
So here's my code to create the columns :

```
/// <summary>
/// Add columns in table according to the sites stored in DB
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The action is used to create site column</remarks>
private void AddColumnSites()
{
    const string siteCol = "SITE_COL";

    var addNewSite = new Action<string>(site =>
    {
        var ultraGridBand = this.CVaultGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0];

        var gridDataColumn = new UltraDataColumn(site);
        gridDataColumn.DataType = typeof(bool);
        gridDataColumn.Tag = siteCol;
        gridDataColumn.DataType = typeof(bool);
        gridDataColumn.DefaultValue = false;
        gridDataColumn.SubObjectPropChanged += this.OnSubObjectPropChanged;
        this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns.AddRange(new object[] {
            gridDataColumn
        });
    });

    for (int i = this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns.Count-1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        if (this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns[i].Tag == siteCol)
        {
            this.CVaultDataSource.Band.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    var sitesDB = from sites in this.lSites
                  orderby sites.KEY
                  select  sites.KEY ;

    foreach (var item in sitesDB)
    {
        addNewSite(item);
    }
}
```

I would like to create a private method to get the state of the checkboxes and returns me the result in a string or a boolean.

Here's a screen :
[image: Example]

Comment: So you have just one row of data, where each column contains a checkbox?

Comment: I have several rows of date (also according to the database). Let me add you a screen in my previous post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method that stores each checkbox value in a `Dictionary<string,bool>` where the string key is the site name and the value is the status true/false according to the checkbox mark. You could pass to this method the UltraGridBand and the UltraGridRow that you are interested to get its values back

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> GetStatusForRow(UltraGridBand b, 
                                                 UltraGridRow row)
{
    Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
    foreach (UltraGridColumn col in b.Columns.Cast<UltraGridColumn>()
                                     .Where(x => x.Tag != null && 
                                            x.Tag.ToString() == "SITE_COL"))
    {
        statusChecked.Add(col.Key, Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[col].Value));
    }
    return statusChecked;
}
```

and read it back with  something like this

```
....
Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked = GetStatusForRow(CVaultGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0], 
                                                         CVaultGrid.ActiveRow);
foreach(KeyValuePair kvp in statusChecked)
   Console.WriteLine("Status site:" + kvp.Key + " is " + kvp.Value.ToString());
```

**EDIT**
To better debug this code you could replace the foreach loop inside GetStatusRow with a more traditional

```
foreach (UltraGridColumn col in b.Columns)
{
    if(col.Tag != null && col.Tag.ToString() == "SITE_COL")
         statusChecked.Add(col.Key, Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[col].Value));
}
```

**EDIT 2**
To loop over all rows and retrieve the values of the checkbox for every row you need something like this

```
private void GetStatusCheckboxes()
{
    foreach (UltraGridRow row in CVaultGrid.Rows)
    {
        Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked;
        statusChecked = GetStatusForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, row);

        // Here you should replace the Console.WriteLine with the code 
        // that uses the status of the current indexed row by the foreach
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> kvp in statusChecked)
            Console.WriteLine("RowIndex=" + row.Index + ", " + 
                              "Status site:" + kvp.Key + " is " + kvp.Value.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
   }
}
```

Comment: It sounds pretty good but I never go inside the foreach loop statusChecked.Add(col.Key, Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[col].Value));``, thanks !

Comment: Well this could be caused from something wrong in the loop inside GetStatusForRow. Let me add a non Linq loop so you could better test with the debugger

Comment: I have a little issue (maybe I should create another subject..), the code works, but it retrieves the checkboxes status of the last row selected. I need to retrieve the checkboxes status of all rows edited. I call the GetStatusForRow method when I click on the Save button.

Comment: The code returns the status of the checkbox for the ActiveRow (it is just one row), if you need the status of every row then you should call this method in a loop (_foreach(UltraGridRow row in grid.Rows)_ ... save data of _row_)

Comment: I've edited my last answer and added what I did, thanks for your help.

Comment: Added an example with foreach on every row of your grid. This could be dangerous in terms of performance if you have many rows.....

Answer (score 0):

@Steve
I just change the type and it's working perfectly !
What you wrote was exactly what I needed ! :D

Here's the code:

```
private Dictionary<string, bool> GetStatusForRow(UltraDataBand b,
                                                 UltraGridRow row)
        {

            Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
            foreach (UltraDataColumn col in b.Columns.Cast<UltraDataColumn>()
                                             .Where(x => x.Tag != null &&
                                                    x.Tag.ToString() == "SITE_COL"))
            {

                statusChecked.Add(col.Key, Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[col.Key].Value));

            }
            return statusChecked;
        }
```

And the call:

```
private void SaveCvaultData()
        {
            GetStatusForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, CVaultGrid.ActiveRow);
            Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked = GetStatusForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, CVaultGrid.ActiveRow);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> kvp in statusChecked)
                MessageBox.Show("Status site:" + kvp.Key + " is " + kvp.Value.ToString());
        }
```

Thank you Steve !

EDIT : Try to retrieve all status.
This is what I did and it's not working :

```
private void GetStatusCheckboxes()
        {
            Dictionary<string, bool> statusChecked = GetStatusForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, CVaultGrid.ActiveRow);
            foreach (UltraGridRow row in CVaultGrid.Rows)
            {
                statusChecked = GetStatusForRow(CVaultDataSource.Band, CVaultGrid.ActiveRow);
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> kvp in statusChecked)
                Console.WriteLine("Status site:" + kvp.Key + " is " + kvp.Value.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
        }
```

Comment: I see it now. Do you have the grid bounded to an UltraDataSource?